# Value Error: x and y must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Let me quickly brief you first, I am working with a .txt file with 5400 data points. Each is a 16 second average over a 24 hour period (24 hrs * 3600 s/hr = 86400...86400/16 = 5400). In short this is the average magnetic strength in the z direction for an inbound particle field curtsy of the Advanced Composition Experiment satellite. Data publicly available [here](http://www.srl.caltech.edu/ACE/ASC/level2/index.html). So when I try to plot it says the error

```
Value Error: x and y must have the same first dimension
```

So I created a numpy lin space of 5400 points broken apart by 16 units. I did this because I thought that my dimensions didn't match with my previous array that I had defined. But now I am sure these two array's are of the same dimension and yet it still gives back that Value Error. The code is as follows:

**First try (without the linspace):**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

Bz = np.loadtxt(r"C:\Users\Schmidt\Desktop\Project\Data\ACE\MAG\ACE_MAG_Data_20151202_GSM.txt", dtype = bytes).astype(float)

Start_ACE = dt.date(2015,12,2)
Finish_ACE = dt.date(2015,12,2)

dt_Mag = 16

time_Mag = np.arange(Start_ACE, Finish_ACE, dt_Mag)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(time_Mag, Bz)
plt.title('Bz 2015 12 02')
```

**Second Try (with linspace):**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

Bz = np.loadtxt(r"C:\Users\Schmidt\Desktop\Project\Data\ACE\MAG\ACE_MAG_Data_20151202_GSM.txt", dtype = bytes).astype(float)

Mag_time = np.linspace(0,5399,16, dtype = float)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(Mag_time, Bz)
plt.title('Bz 2015 12 02')
```

Other than it being a dimensional problem I don't know what else could be holding back this plotting procedure back.

**Full traceback:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-c5dc0bdf5117> in <module>()
      1 plt.subplot(3,1,1)
----> 2 plt.plot(Mag_time, Bz)
      3 plt.title('Bz 2015 12 02')

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3152         ax.hold(hold)
   3153     try:
-> 3154         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3155     finally:
   3156         ax.hold(washold)

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1809                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1810                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1811             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1812         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1813         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1422             kwargs['color'] = c
   1423 
-> 1424         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1425             self.add_line(line)
   1426             lines.append(line)

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                 return
    385             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 386                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    387                     yield seg
    388                 return

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    362             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    363 
--> 364         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    365 
    366         if self.command == 'plot':

C:\Users\Schmidt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    221         y = _check_1d(y)
    222         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 223             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
    224         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    225             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Comment: Please add the entire error message including the stack trace

Comment: added the full traceback readout for the linspace condition

Comment: What does `print(Bz.shape)` show?

Comment: The resultant of the code: (5400, )

Comment: What's the length (shape) of `Mag_time`?  It should match `Bz`.  In the `linspace` case `Mag_time` only has 16 elements.

Comment: i found out it was only 16. So I switched the Mag_time from a linspace to arange. Now I know for sure they are of the same dimension and it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the selection of array creation. Instead of linspace, I should have used arange.

```
Mag_time = np.arange(0,86400, 16, dtype = float)
```